# how to restrict inserting values for a specific column in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I will have a column for id and I am using serial type, so it generates a number independently. I would like to restrict inserting custom values for that column.

Comment: row security policy won't help here I suppose - you can create a trigger, that ignores NEW.id replacing it by nexvat(seq)

Answer (score 0):

With the `t` table:

```
create table t (
    c1 serial,
    c2 text
);
```

Revoke privileges on the serial column from the public and all other roles:

```
revoke insert (c1), update (c1) on t from public, other_role;
```

Grant privileges on the serial column to `the_role`:

```
grant insert (c1), update (c1) on t to the_role;
```